# Telescoping constructor

Tags: c++, design-patterns

From  Effective Java 2ed Item 2:

> telescoping constructor pattern, in which you provide a constructor
>   with only the required parameters, another with a single optional
>   parameter, a third with two optional parameters, and so on,
>   culminating in a constructor with all the optional parameter

Can I do the same in C++? I tried somthing like this:

```
MyClass::MyClass(QWidget *parent)
{   
    MyClass(NULL, NULL, NULL, parent);
}

MyClass::MyClass(QString title, QWidget *parent) 
{

    MyClass(title, NULL, NULL, parent);
}

MyClass::MyClass(QString title, QString rightButton, QWidget *parent)
{


    MyClass(title, NULL, rightButton, parent);
}



MyClass::MyClass(QString titleLabel, QString leftButtonLabel, QString rightButtonLabel, QWidget *parent)
: QWidget(parent)
{
      // construct the object
}
```

but it does not work. Any hint?

I am really new in C++ field so.. sorry for the newbee question

Comment: yes, you can.  it's easy.  You even show how in the last constructor there.

Comment: Note that your code is merely constructing a temporary `MyClass` in the constructor, since it's not in the member initializer list

Comment: Just use default arguments for the parameters, done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to supply default values to the constructor parameters.

If that doesn't work, you typically create an `Init` method that gets called by each constructor so that the code isn't repeated.

Answer (score 10):

This is called delegating constructor in c++11 and is done like so:

```
MyClass::MyClass(QWidget *parent)
    : MyClass(NULL, NULL, NULL, parent)
{   
}
```

whereas your version produces a temporary that gets immediately destroyed.

Comment: illegal member initialization: 'MyClass' is not a base or member, on visual studio 2005

Comment: @blackbelt this is only legal since c++11, use a modern compiler.

Comment: @blackbelt Visual Studio does not support this C++11 feature even in 2010 SP1 ... they might catch up in VS2012.

Comment: @AJG85: VS2012 is already in pre-release, and no more features are added, so no.

Comment: @blackbelt he did caveat it with being a C++11 feature, thus it would be expected to not work with Visual Studio 2005. Even with the latest version of Visual Studio delegating constructors are not planned to be supported (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx).

Comment: This makes so much sense! It should have been part of the earlier standard.

Answer (score 1):

```
MyClass::MyClass(QWidget *parent)
{   
    MyClass(NULL, NULL, NULL, parent);
}
```

should be

```
MyClass::MyClass(QWidget *parent) :
    MyClass(NULL, NULL, NULL, parent)
{   
}
```

etc.

Comment: In C++11, that is. C++03 doesn't have delegating ctors.

Comment: @Xeo When I posted this I was thinking derived constructor so I deleted, then was reminded by your comment that it will be supported in C++11. Thanks.